# Re-synchronizing timestamps of InfluxDB values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, influxdb, telegraf

I have several values being put into an InfluxDB under different topics. They are provided via MQTT/JSON and processed by Telegraf. Each JSON record results in a tuple of entries in different series that have *slightly* different timestamps. The ∆ is typically below 1 millisecond whereas the JSON events are several seconds apart, so detecting should be manageable.

For further analysis it is necessary to re-group the entries so that the tuples are united again. Simply rounding the timestamp would do in most cases, but of course not generally because a boundary may lie just in between such a tuple.

Any ideas? I am accessing data via Python, so either an appropriate Influx query or processing in Python will do. Of course I can scan through the data in a loop and decide how to put them together, but I wonder if there is an elegant solution already at hand, maybe using one of the common Python libraries such as NumPy or Pandas. I assume I am not the only person who is faced with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I opted for processing my data in Python. This is what I came up with. It can handle arbitrary granularity intervals. It's fast enough for the data volume I am handling; apart from the sort, it's O(n).

```
# input is res: dictionary of {timestamp: (topic, value)}
DELTA = timedelta(seconds=0.5) # granularity; adjust to needs
t = datetime(dt.MINYEAR, 1, 1, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)  # init running tstamp var
t_group = t # timestamp for sample group
outlist = [] # output list
group = None # current sample group
for key, (topic, val) in sorted(res.items()):
  if (key - t) > DELTA: # new group
    t_group = key
    if group: outlist.append(group) # save previous group to output list
    group = {"time": t_group} # init new group with 1st timestamp
  print(f"{t_group}\t{key}\t{topic} = {val}\t∆={key-t}")
  group[topic] = val # add to group
  t = key
print(f"\n{len(outlist)} entries extracted.\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could process the data with Flux and use the date command on the timestamp to truncate it essentially to a different granularity, say by date.minute() or date.millisecond().

Perhaps create a new field, like newg and either replace the _time field with it using set or adapt your exist queries to use the new column?

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with newg: date.millisecond(t: r._time) }))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have a further look into Flux :)
I opted for processing the data within my Python script, because rounding/truncating would sometimes split linked data.